# Can't see the value of variables in debug mode with VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to use the C++ debugger in VS Code. I have created the launch.json file with the configuration but I have the problem that I cannot see the value of the string type variables, nor of the collections. Numeric variables are displayed correctly. I have tried several solutions but they have not worked for me and I can't find any answers on other sites.

[Trouble debugging with VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGuah.png)

The configuration files are the following:

**launch.json**

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C/C++: g++ Compilar y depurar el archivo activo",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Habilitar la impresión con sangría para gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Establecer tipo de desensamblado en Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "text": "set charset UTF-8"
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ compilar archivo activo",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

**tasks.json**

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ compilar archivo activo",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Tarea generada por el depurador."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

I'm using Debian 10, the compiler is g++ (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0

What I expect to see is to be able to see the literal value of the string, for example "test string", but it doesn't show the value but other information about the variable.

Comment: please describe clearly in words what you are seeing and what you expect to see.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this guide if you are working on Linux.

[Using C++ on Linux in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux)

Make sure you follow the instructions correctly. In my case, I did not have the gdb package installed, so the debugger did not work correctly.

```
sudo apt install gdb
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a Macintosh, so I use LLDB and not GDB. I prefer LLDB, but I am unsure if it's a Debugger issue. Can you please share the output for the following

```
void debug(int x,string str,string (&ref)[2]){

return; } //add a breakpoint here

int main(){
int x{3};
string str_x {"Single_String"};
string s[]{"hello","world"};
debug(x,str_x,s);}
```

Some people refer to the containers wrong in the debug mode. In the watch add `ref,2`

You should see your containers like this

[Watch for a container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9tpv.png)

Let me know what you see, based on that I can answer your question.